# I want RowCommand executed before RowCreate reloading OR something like this

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have

```
<asp:GridView>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PsyHealth">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PsyHealth" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="-">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="Gen" CommandName="Gen" runat="server" Text="gen" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var dataItem = e.Row.DataItem as ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel;
        var psyHealth = e.Row.FindControl("PsyHealth") as PlaceHolder;
        if (psyHealth != null)
        {
            psyHealth.Controls.Add(dataItem.PsyHeath);
        }
    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //bla bla bla
}
```

but when I clicked the `Gen` `LinkButton` on the page. The `GridView1_RowCreated` was triggered first and threw the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` because the `e.Row.DataItem` was null.

Edit: The Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel> utViewModelList = new List<ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel> { };

    utViewModelList = utRepo.GetUserTestorViewModelListByHrId();

    this.GridView1.DataSource = utViewModelList;
    this.GridView1.DataBind();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    }
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowCreated);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your RowCreated Code ? It would be better if you post complete form and code behind.

Comment: I updated the post about `GridView1_RowCreated`. `GridView1_RowCommand` has no code yet and the problem is I can never run into there.

Comment: Can you make sure, that your gridview in rebind on postback ?

Comment: Please post your code behind and show me the place where you binding dataSource to your Gridview

Comment: I edited the post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

When you click any button in the gridview , your page is postbacked and the page load event is called before it goes into the `RowCommand` event. In the page load event you are binding your gridview again and that's why your `RowCreated Event` is called.

You have to bind your gridview under `if (!IsPostBack)`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (!IsPostBack)
{
    List<ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel> utViewModelList = new List<ViewModels.UserTestorViewModel> { };

utViewModelList = utRepo.GetUserTestorViewModelListByHrId();

this.GridView1.DataSource = utViewModelList;
this.GridView1.DataBind();
   }
}
```

**Edit:** Now I got your issue after you posted code..

The problem is here in `Page_Init`, can you remove the event handler from here and try the following:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.RowCreated += new GridViewRowEventHandler(GridView1_RowCreated);
}
```

add here

```
<asp:GridView  onrowcreated="GridView1_RowCreated">
```

Comment: Not work. All remains the same. It ran into `RowCreate` and die.

Comment: Then there must be the problem in your Row Created event.

Comment: Not work. Now it's `<asp:GridView onRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated">`. Problem still there. It ran into RowCreate and die.

Answer (score 0):

Can you store the utViewModelList in Session first time you get it? If so then you can get the UserTestorViewModel instance from saved by the selected row's DataKey value.

Comment: It's depends on where you store the session. If it stored in database then yes, it affect the performance. If it stored InProc then you rather waste a memory but performance will affected slightly. Actually you can only store entity Id's along with label instances instead of entities.